# IPP Everywhere ( IPP 2.0 ) Server Basic Authentication

Tags: windows, server, printing

We are attempting to develop and IPP Everywhere Printing Server ( IPP 2.0 ) and are having issue with Windows 10 / 11 when attempting to authenticate the clients using Basic Authentication

When we run the system as IPP 1.0 and add using "Select a shared printer by name" and selecting the Microsoft / PostScript Driver everything works as expected.
But we have now updated the server to conform to the IPP 2.0 standard, and we are able to add the printer.. but when we attempt to print and challenge the Client with a 401 Unauthorized (WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm" ) the print job is marked as "Error" and the client is never challenged for its credentials.

We add it using the "Add a printer using the ip address or hostname" we see incoming requests using IPP v2 to the printer server, and the printer is added successfully. But when we attempt to print and challenge using Basic Auth the print fails, if we disable Auth everything works

We have made sure to clear everything, changed printer-uuid etc to ensure no credentials are stored..

Is there anything specific that the Windows 10/11 IPP Everywhere Drivers require ?

Our printer uri is https://URL and we are running an valid SSL certificate

Could it be that Windows 10 / 11 dosent support Basic Auth for IPP 2.0+?

Or what else could be wrong

We have also tried with the following project and get the same issue:

https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample

This is linked from this site as an example project for IPP Everywhere

https://pwg.org/ipp/everywhere.html

We have submitted and issue here where a log file can be found for the ippsample project

https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample/issues/283